# correct use of MAX3232 for a single TTL to RS232 connection

Tags: datasheet, level-shifting, max3232

I am using the MAX3232 chip for doing TTL to RS232 conversion. Datasheet available here:

http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/max3232.pdf

The chip is dual channel, but I only need to use one channel. I follow the schematic of Fig 8 of the datasheet.

[image]

However I noticed the following: if I use pins 7, 8, 9, 10 to do a level conversion, but I let the pins 11, 12, 13, and 14 float, the chip does not work as expected. If I put pins 11, 12, 13, 14 to +5V, everything works fine. I guess this is because even if not in used, pins 11 to 14 should not be let floating and should have some impedance connected (I guess a serial port is like a high impedance in a sense?).

My questions are:

- Am I right?
- I cannot find a place in the datasheet where this is explained. Am I missing something?
- I guess putting all to 5V is not optimal (some of the inputs are 3.3V as some of the pints are TTL). Is there a better way of doing so? Maybe a way to even keep the chip working with a single channel, but make it possible for later use to connect one more channel (if I get a PCB produced for example)?

## EDIT

Now I understand. I was wrong about which chip I was using, thank you for pointing that the TI and the MAXIMs chips are different. This is then a closed issue: see datasheet p 11:

https://no.mouser.com/datasheet/2/256/MAX3322E-MAX3323E-77424.pdf

Comment: Unused logic inputs must be connected to a logic supply or ground, if necessary via resistors.

Comment: What exactly happens? What goes wrong?

Comment: It is just not working. I think the comment by Andy aka is what I need.

Comment: I seem to recall reading similar to what Andy wrote in the data sheet.  most parts require extra inputs to be connected to something.

Comment: @Zorglub29 - Hi, Based on your description of the behaviour, I wonder if this is a *genuine* TI MAX3232 to match the linked datasheet. Is it actually on a small adapter PCB bought ready-assembled from Amazon / Ebay / AliExpress etc.?

Comment: No, it is a chip bought from a legit reseller, produced by MAXIMs

Comment: @Zorglub29 - "*it is a chip bought from a legit reseller, produced by MAXIMs*" Thanks. So the datasheet & layout image need to be fixed in the question to point to the Maxim (not TI) datasheet. Unless you've compared every single detail between them, we can't be sure that readers won't be misled by differences between the TI datasheet and your Maxim parts. FYI some of the original test was invalid (*outputs* shouldn't be shorted to a power rail) but since you've mentioned that Andy's comment helped, I won't interrupt further. Thanks for explaining the source of the devices.

Comment: @SamGibson : oooh, you are right. I had never thought that chips having similar pinout, name and function could work differently depending om the manufakturer... Stupid of me. I will correct.

Comment: @Zorglub29 - Unfortunately you've been looking at the wrong Maxim datasheet, and so come to the wrong conclusion :-( I wasn't hinting about a big difference, when I pointed out the TI datasheet was linked, but you were using a (believed to be) Maxim chip - just that *subtle* differences in spec may exist. You have looked at and linked the datasheet including the MAX**3322** but you need [this datasheet](https://pdfserv.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX3222-MAX3241.pdf) for the MAX**3232**. Those two ICs *do* have different pinouts. Follow Andy's advice with the correct Maxim datasheet & re-test.

Comment: @SamGibson many thanks for your help. I got confused with all of those datasheets ;) Anyway, my device is working fine now...

Comment: @Zorglub29 - You're welcome :-) Yes, the similar numbers are confusing, and it doesn't help that several parts share a datasheet! "*my device is working fine now*" Great! Please can you write an answer explaining what the problem was? (Was it just the floating logic input on pin 11, that was the cause? FYI the RS-232 inputs, like on pin 13, have an internal pull-down, and so a floating RS-232 input *shouldn't* be a problem. Anyway, it'll help future readers if you can document your solution and, after the system-imposed delay of 48hrs, accept it, if no-one suggests anything better :-) Thanks.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the chip I use is a MAXIMs chip that has a different datasheet than the TI one. My chip is actually a one channel chip. I got confused because of initially using schematics from google. My bad, thank you for helping me find the answer with your comments.

https://no.mouser.com/datasheet/2/256/MAX3322E-MAX3323E-77424.pdf

Comment: That's the wrong datasheet (unfortunately there are several ICs with similar numbers!) and the Maxim MAX3232 *is* a dual channel chip. See my comment under the question. Therefore I believe this answer is incorrect and should be deleted, as it cannot be the correct answer, if you really have the Maxim MAX**3232**.